# Wakanda tutorial (angular 4): can not create angular components with angular cli

Tags: angular-cli, wakanda

Trying out the wakanda angular 4 todo tutorial:
https://wakanda.github.io/doc/#/tutorial?section=main

> Can not create angular components in step 2: Error message in the
>   console after trying to generate an angular component: "You have to be
>   inside an Angular CLI project in order to use the generate command."

Environment:
@angular/cli: 1.1.0
node: 7.5,0
os win32 x64

Tried to update "@angular/cli" version from "1.0.0" in package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.1.0"
```

But it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: rename duplicated file `.angular-cli.json` to `angular-cli.jso` (duplicated without leading dot).